# Reverse LIKE function to find a substring of the search term

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I have an page that the function is to search data.

I have in my table column like this :

```
form_no | status
1       | WW025687732
2       | QR1233545AB
```

The GET function :

```
$status = $_GET['status_sheet'];
```

I using the SQL like this :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_test WHERE status LIKE '$status%'");
```

When I search WW025687732 with more text or number like this WW025687732-1224AS.
It can't function. If the status contains WW025687732 and what ever if I add more text like this WW025687732-1224AS, it will show.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). Also maybe read up a bit on SQL injection attacks. As for the question, try to echo the query, can you post here what you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_test WHERE status LIKE '%$status%'");
```

See this [**LINK**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)

LONG texts will need to be an full text search

Comment: Wouldn't this match stuff that _contains_ the the status rather than start with it?

Comment: it will search for all the data that contains the $status,OP had a query to find the status that must starts with $status

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM t_test WHERE status = SUBSTRING('$status', LENGTH(status));");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is that the variable assignment isn't occurring correctly and mysql is getting `SELECT * FROM t_test WHERE status LIKE '%'`

double check you form method an ensure that it is in fact `get` and that the variable name of the search field is `status_sheet`.

Also it would be a good idea to make sure your status contains at least one character before sending it to the query:

```
if (strlen($status) > 0){
    echo "Error you must specify something for this to work.";
} else { 
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_test WHERE status LIKE '$status%'");
    .... show results and whatever ....
}
```